# Jupyter Notebook syntax highlighting not working

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I recently installed Anaconda 3 and after a few minor issues I was able to run Jupyter Notebook, but **syntax highlighting is not working at all**. Everything else seems to be working fine.

I had Anaconda 2 installed before, deleted all it's directories (with jupyter's dirs along with it) prior to downloading and installing Anaconda 3.

I don't think this forced-uninstall of Anaconda 2 is the reason for this problem because Anaconda 3 files should all be contained in its installation, right?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if it will help, but let it be here for history. I use **Anaconda 3** on windows 10 (64), **Jupyter** syntax always worked (**Google Chrome** browser). Today I launched **QtConsole** before **Notebook**. Any actions inside **QtConsole** were performed AFTER I opened **Notebook** and saw a lack of syntax highlight. So it doesn't matter what exactly I did inside the console. I've noticed that problem was fixed after the following sequence: I closed **QtConsole** and I've restarted **Kernel** via upper menu (**Kernel => Restart and Clear Output**).

Comment: I only had to do this; "Kernel > Restart and Clear Output" worked for me! Thanks

Comment: I have this problem as well (i.e. syntax not highlighted on notebook cells) and this worked! For future reference, I also had a previous installation of anaconda (on windows), something went wrong, so I uninstalled and installed miniconda, aaaaaand the problems started.

Comment: In my case I had to toggle dark reader off then on again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hard refresh the browser
On MacOS is command + shift + R (open your browser first)
Find the equivalent for your OS

Answer (score -2):

I had this same issue. If you go up to the menu bar of your kernel window, the very last item in the menu bar will have either "Raw" or "Markdown"

Click on it and change it to "Code" and this should resolve the issue